# C ++ singleton mode code can not run, I do not know why？

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

this is my single cases of models code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class CSingleton  
{  
private:  
    CSingleton()
    {  
    }  
    static CSingleton *m_pInstance;  
public:  
    static CSingleton * GetInstance()  
    {  
        if(m_pInstance == NULL)  
            m_pInstance = new CSingleton();  
        return m_pInstance;  
    }  
};  
int main() {
    CSingleton* p1 = CSingleton::GetInstance();
    return 0;
}
```

when i run this code,the following error apper   `undefined reference to CSingleton::m_pInstance`,I do not know where I am wrong, I just want to write a single model.can someone help me?

Comment: You have declared `m_pInstance`, but haven't defined it. Add this line at file level, outside of any function or class definition: `CSingleton* CSingleton::m_pInstance = nullptr;`

Comment: This is 2017, people still use *singleton!!!!!*

Comment: @army007, it's 2017 and people still use *COBOL* :-) Singletons are still useful *despite* being labelled an anti-pattern based on some people *misusing* them. In that sense, it's in the same boat as `goto`, multiple return points from a function and side-effects, all of which can also be misused, but are quite good in certain circumstances.

Comment: @paxdiablo, so-far I have not seen anyone used it in any good place. I have only seen misuse of it in many places. Evey where the use of singleton could be replaced by DI. It is hard to write unittest for classes who use singleton.

Answer (score 2):

Outside of the class (and outside of `main`), you need to *define* that variable over and above just *declaring* it (as in your class):

```
CSingleton *CSingleton::m_pInstance = nullptr;
```

You'll also noticed I've used `nullptr` rather than `NULL` or `0` - this is a better way to do null pointers in modern C++ compilers.

---

The following complete program shows how to do this:

```
include <iostream>

class CSingleton {
    private:
        static CSingleton *m_pInstance;
        CSingleton() {
            std::cout << "Instantiating\n";
        }
    public:
        static CSingleton *GetInstance() {
            if (m_pInstance == nullptr) {
                m_pInstance = new CSingleton();
            }
            std::cout << "Delivering\n";
            return m_pInstance;
        }
};
CSingleton *CSingleton::m_pInstance = nullptr;

int main() {
    CSingleton* p1 = CSingleton::GetInstance();
    CSingleton* p2 = CSingleton::GetInstance();
    CSingleton* p3 = CSingleton::GetInstance();
    return 0;
}
```

As expected, it outputs:

```
Instantiating
Delivering
Delivering
Delivering
```

Comment: This is the first time I tried to use the singleton model, there was a very idiot. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to use singleton, use Meyers' one:

```
class CSingleton  
{  
private:  
    CSingleton() = default;
    CSingleton(const CSingleton&) = delete;
    CSingleton& operator=(const CSingleton&) = delete;
public:  
    static CSingleton& GetInstance()
    {  
        static CSingleton instance;
        return instance;  
    }  
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to **initialize** the static data member of your singleton class. Which can be done outside your class as below-

```
CSingleton *CSingleton::m_pInstance = nullptr;
```

And yes, if you really want to use the best version of Singleton, you should use Meyer's version as suggested by **@Jarod42**. Because that is thread-safe and that's a preferred design for low latency system.